# Getting the most common word in a column while displaying the other column that it is directly related

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables that I joined. Columns(SKU, Detailed Description) come from table 1. Column(Simple Description) comes from table 2.

| a.SKU | b.Detailed Description | c.Simple Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | Salmon Trout | Fish |
| 654321 | Sea Bass | Tool |

Column c has 99 unique possible strings.

Column b has a very large amount of unique strings. But some of them have some words in common.

I need to get the most common words that appear in column b but at the same time get what simple description is attached to the those common words.

I have tried this and it did not work.

```
WITH E1(N) AS (
    SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES
        (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
    ) t(N)
),
E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a CROSS JOIN E1 b),
E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a CROSS JOIN E2 b)

SELECT TOP 50
    a.SKU
    a.DESCRIPTION,
    b.[Detailed_description]

FROM table1 a
inner join table2 b
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT 
        ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY l.N1),
        Item       = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(a.DESCRIPTION, l.N1, l.L1)))
        FROM (
            SELECT s.N1,
                L1 = ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(' ',a.DESCRIPTION,s.N1),0)-s.N1,4000)
            FROM(
                SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                SELECT t.N+1 
                FROM(
                    SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(a.DESCRIPTION)/2,0))
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
                    FROM E4
                ) t(N)
                WHERE SUBSTRING(a.DESCRIPTION ,t.N,1) = ' '
            ) s(N1)
        ) l(N1, L1)
) x
WHERE x.item <> ''
GROUP BY x.item
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Data hygiene is a constant battle.  There is no query that knows Salmon is a FISH and not a COLOR.   There is no option but to go heads down and perform the scrub.

Comment: There's no data integrity in what you have posted and your description is not particularly clear - what business rule can you describe that knows "Tool" is incorrect. At best it sounds like you need to join with some sort of mapping table of allowable or associative words to identify potential issues. but building that mapping table is probably as time consuming as just manually fixing the data.

Comment: Have I been living under a rock and Sea Bass has changed from being a fish to a tool?

Answer (score 0):

According to the data you provided, this script should give you what you need.

This does make the assumption that each word in column B is to be handled individually (i.e. "Sea" and "Bass" rather than "Sea Bass")

```
--Create the sample data (as per the question)
create table #so_73975533(
    SKU nvarchar(10),
    [Detailed Description] nvarchar(512),
    [Description] nvarchar(512)
)

insert into #so_73975533
values ('123456', N'Salmon Trout',N'Fish'),
('654321', N'Sea Bass',N'Tool')

select * from #so_73975533

/*
Adapted from Jeff Moden's brilliance
https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/the-numbers-or-tally-table-what-it-is-and-how-it-replaces-a-loop-1
*/
--===== Create and populate the Tally table on the fly
 SELECT TOP 100000
        IDENTITY(INT,1,1) AS N
   INTO #Tally
   FROM Master.dbo.SysColumns sc1,
        Master.dbo.SysColumns sc2

--===== Add a Primary Key to maximize performance
  ALTER TABLE #Tally
    ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Tally_N 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (N) WITH FILLFACTOR = 100

--Get all the words out of column B using SKU as a key
select a.SKU, substring(' '+a.[Detailed Description]+' ',N+1,charindex(' ',' '+a.[Detailed Description]+' ', N+1)-N-1) as Word
into #commonWords
from #Tally t
cross join #so_73975533 a
WHERE N < Len(' '+a.[Detailed Description]+' ')
and SUBSTRING(' '+a.[Detailed Description]+' ',N,1) = ' '

--As there are only 4 distinct words in column B
--just take the top 2 - expand as necessary
select top 2
Word, count(Word)
from #commonWords
group by Word
order by 2

--Fetch all of the column C values where one of the most popular
--words exists in column B 
select distinct a.[Description]
from #so_73975533 a
inner join #commonWords b on charindex(b.Word, a.[Detailed Description],1)>0

--Clean up
drop table #so_73975533
DROP TABLE #Tally
drop table #commonWords
```